# Setting up Ruby on Rails beginner netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

WOW. Setting up is complicated, can anyone recommend a link or provide me with some advice.

I have two options, a Linux Hosting server with it pre-installed or through NetBeans.

Sorry for the generic question.

Comment: Hey try redcar for an editor "sudo gem install redar" "sudo redcar install" and use heroku.com for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are going to want both of your options. You will want to have a hosting server with Rails installed on which you will deploy your Rails application. You will want to use NetBeans on your development machine to develop the application in the first place.

It is good to note that using NetBeans is not mandatory; you can -- and many others do -- use any random text editor for building Rails applications. However, I use NetBeans for Rails development, as I find that it greatly increases my productivity.

Don't let yourself get overwhelmed by the feeling of complexity at the beginning. While getting on to the learning curve can be tricky for any system, I believe that climbing the curve with Rails is easier than with many or most other web application frameworks.